# Databricks - hand spaces and - in column name

Tags: azure, databricks, databricks-sql

I need to create a table in my dev catalog and its the second column thats the issue, when I run the below, I get the error

```
CREATE TABLE dev.base_header(
Hdr_Template_Version string,
`Excel - Unstructured` string, 
Hdr_LossDataExcessCurrency string)
```

Error
Found invalid character(s) among ' ,;{}()\n\t=' in the column names of your schema. Please use other characters and try again.

I know its to do with the backticks but I just cant seem to get it right, was wondering if someone could give me an assist on this as its driving me mad, spent the last 2 hours trying to figure it out.

Thanks,

Nic

Comment: @Are you using Azure databricks?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, yes I am, trying to run it via a notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The following limitations apply for all object names in Unity Catalog Databricks:**

**The following special characters are not allowed:**

- Period (.)
- Space ( )
- Forward slash (/)
- All ASCII control characters (00-1F hex)
- The DELETE character (7F hex)

**using backticks,we can escape names that contain special characters such as hyphens (-) but not the special characters that are mentioned above.**

*Below DDL should work fine without space character.*

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE base_header(
Hdr_Template_Version string,
`Excel-Unstructured` string, 
Hdr_LossDataExcessCurrency string)
```

[https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-names.html#table-name][Databricks Documentation]